# problems while trying to communicate between ATMEL mega169 and ATMEL flash

Tags: avr, spi, flash

**Hello everyone**

I'm writing a C program that will access a flash AT45DB041B from the controller ATmega169. I'm using a Butterfly development kit.

I have succeeded to read the status register and get correct data so I'm quite sure that the flash works and can communicate. But I haven't been able to write and read to flash, the only thing that I can read from it is zeros.

I unfortunately I don't have any possibility to snoop the traffic either.

init:

```
 void init_flash_as_master(void)
 {

// double speed, p 150 mega169 manual
SPSR = 0x01; // the other bits are don't care or set by hardware

//      MOSI        SCK         !SS    are outputs
DDRB |= _BV(PB2) | _BV(PB1) | _BV(PB0);


// p 148 in mega169 manual
/* bit 7, 0 interrupt not enabled
 * bit 6, 1 SPI enable,
 * bit 5, 0, MSB first, ch 5 flash datasheet
 * bit 4, 1, Master
 * bit 3,2, 00, CPOL,CPHA, SPI mode 0, p 5 flash datasheet
 * bit 1,0, 10, /32, flash max operating frequency 20 MHz p 1 flash datasheet
 */

SPCR = 0x52;

}
```

send:

```
inline void send_byte(uint8_t byte)
{
    SPDR = byte;
    while (!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF))) {;}
}
```

recive:

```
inline uint8_t recieve_byte(void) 
{
SPDR = 'A'; //load SPDR to start clock generation
while (!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF))) {;}
return SPDR;
}
```

start transmission:

```
inline void start_transmission(void) 
{
    // set chip select for sending data
    PORTB &= 0xFE; // setting bit 0 on port B low
}
```

stop transmission:

```
inline void stop_transmission(void) 
{
    // finish transmission
    PORTB |= 0x01;
}
```

clear flag:

```
inline void clear_SPIF(void)
{
    uint8_t temp = 0;

    // clear SPIF
    if(SPSR & _BV(SPIF)) { temp = SPDR; }
}
```

write operation:

```
// write a struct song_t to specified page in the flash memory
void flash_write_song(uint16_t page, const song_t * song)
{
    if (direction != master) init_flash_as_master();

    clear_SPIF();
    start_transmission();
    // ch. 12.2 flash datasheet 
    send_byte(0x84); // write to buffer 1, 84h
    send_byte(0x00); // three address bytes, starting at byte 0
    send_byte(0x00); // table 7, flash application note
    send_byte(0x00);

    // push name
    for (int i = 0; i != NAME_LEN; i++)
    {
        send_byte(song->name[i]);
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (j < TUNE_LEN) 
    {
        send_byte(song->tune[j]);
        j++;
}
stop_transmission();

flash_ready();

start_transmission();
// ch. 12.3 flash datasheet

    // Buffer 1 to Main Memory Page Program with Built-in Erase
send_byte(0x83); 

    // first byte contains the 4 uppermost bits
send_byte(get_high_byte(page));

    // second byte contains the 7 lowest bits, starting at bit 1
send_byte(get_low_byte(page)); 
send_byte(0x00); // table 7, flash application note

stop_transmission();
flash_ready();

}
```

read operation:

```
// read a struct song_t from specified page in the flash memory
void flash_read_song(uint16_t page, song_t * song)
{

if (direction != master) init_flash_as_master();

clear_SPIF();

// flash datasheet 16.2
start_transmission();

// table 7, flash application note
send_byte(0xD2); // read page from main memory,
// first byte contains the 4 uppermost bits
send_byte(get_high_byte(page)); 
// second byte contains the 7 lowest bits, starting at bit 1
send_byte(get_low_byte(page)); 
send_byte(0x00); // controller says, read from byte 0

send_byte(0x00); // 4 don't care bytes
send_byte(0x00);
send_byte(0x00);
send_byte(0x00);

// read name
for (int i = 0; i != NAME_LEN; i++)
{
    song->name[i] = recieve_byte(); 
}
/*  // and now we will read the data until we find a 0
int j = 0;
uint8_t byte_popped = recieve_byte();
while (j < 4) //TODO
{
    song->tune[j] = byte_popped;
    j++;
    byte_popped = recieve_byte();
}
*/
stop_transmission();
```

}

**The question**

I am quite sure that the error is in my code, as I can read the status register. But I can't see any problems in my code. Am I pulling the right signals in the right time?

If you want any clarifications or more descriptions, please tell.
*Regards*
Gorgen

Comment: can you give probes of signals? Can you please post your code to this site instead of pastebin? We really cannot help easily without for more information. I am closing this and when you are ready to make updates let me know and I will reopen(just flag for moderator attention).

Comment: it seems someone already helped you. I have reopened, but it seems the question is pretty much solved. The things I want to note is that someone really could use a schematic and probed signals for a more complicated problem. As the solution seems to be relatively easy and very specific to your situation I closed it. With code someone now has a full guide for interfacing with this flash. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @Kortuk: I will.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can spot is that `stop_transmission()` is missing from `flash_ready()`.

Your programming sequence is:

1. fill buffer
2. wait for ready
3. program
4. wait for ready

The program command may be lost since it is not preceded by a falling edge of $\overline{\text{CS}}$.